# Authenticate using openID without login through provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetopenauth, myspace

I create web application to connect to MySpace Offsite App and I want to authenticate I used the following code

```
var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
            IAuthenticationRequest request = openid.CreateRequest("http://www.myspace.com/thabet084");
            request.AddExtension(new OAuthRequest("ConsumerKey"));
            request.RedirectToProvider();
            var response = openid.GetResponse();
            OAuthResponse oauthExtension = new OAuthResponse();
            if (response != null)
            {

                switch (response.Status)
                {
                    case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                        oauthExtension = response.GetExtension<OAuthResponse>();
                        var user_authorized_request_token = oauthExtension.RequestToken;
                        break;
                }
            }
             OffsiteContext context = new OffsiteContext("ConsumerKey", "ConsumerSecret");

            var accessToken = (AccessToken)context.GetAccessToken(oauthExtension.RequestToken, "", "");
```

and I used the following refrences DotNetOpenAuth.dll and MySpaceID.SDK.dll

My problems are:

1. I always found that responce=null
2. I don't need user to login through provider MySpace so i need to remove RedirectToProvider();

My application in brief is to send status from mywebsite to MySpace account Just click on button to send

All ideas are welcome

BR,
Mohammed Thabet Zaky

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to authenticate the user then OpenID isn't what you want at all.  In fact, OAuth probably isn't either.  If you just want to send the user to MySpace to confirm a status message, you can very likely do that with just a crafted URL the way Twitter does -- no special protocol or library required at all.

Comment: thanks Andrew for your reply ,but I created the same application with twitter but not using crafted url, I used Twitterizer api . so how can I use crafted url in MySpace